# How to create a new object in play template / How to import a class in play template

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using play framework I have to create a JSONObject in my template like this

```
JSONObject unreadCount = new JSONObject(unreadString);
```

I get unreadString value only in my template. So i need to create object in my template
To create a new object i need to import the class. But i don't know how to import.

[This one](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=how%20to%20import%20classess%20in%20play%20templates&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/6d0c5aa038a5c2cf?fwc=1&ei=x8DYTtDAD8nlrAed04ztDQ&usg=AFQjCNHb4Lfe9vg_aeij8qWk-Rcp22j8nA&cad=rja) doesnot help much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arasu, you ahve the answer in the link you yourself provide:

```
No you can't do that. Just use the full qualified name of your classes instead.
```

That is, you can't import in templates, you have to use full paths. For example:

```
java.util.List
```